# Apache showing Permission denied: flask_session error

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi, flask-session

Im trying to get flask with virtual environment and wsgi configured to work but Apache keeps giving me this error:

> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179153 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]     app.session_interface = self._get_interface(app)
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179160 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]   File "/var/www/html/project/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_session/**init**.py",
>   line 93, in _get_interface
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179163 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]     config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'], config['SESSION_PERMANENT'])
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179169 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]   File "/var/www/html/project/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py",
>   line 314, in **init**
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179172 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]     self.cache = FileSystemCache(cache_dir, threshold=threshold, mode=mode)
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179177 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]   File "/var/www/html/project/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/cache.py",
>   line 717, in **init**
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179180 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]     os.makedirs(self._path)
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179185 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]   File "/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179188 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx]     mkdir(name, mode)
>
> [Tue Nov 13 13:23:55.179215 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11819] [x.x.x.x:xxxx] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/flask_session'

I tried giving the project different permissions but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

The directory is failing to be created is on behalf of `flask-session`, which has a `SESSION_FILE_DIR` setting that'll let you override its default. Point that to some place with the appropriate permissions, and you'll likely be fine.

Comment: Find someone who understands Window permissions. I did, but that was back in the Windows XP/Windows 7 days.

Comment: its on a linux machine

Comment: Oh, duh. I mixed this up with a similar problem. :/
By any chance is SELinux involved?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify which type of session interface to use.

Try to set the `SESSION-TYPE` to `"null"`.